# ActiveModel::Callbacks access properties in callback function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two classes:

1) An API (ApiClient) responsible for making HTTP requests (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE).

```
require 'faraday'

module Assets
  class ApiClient
    extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
    define_model_callbacks :post, :put, :delete

    after_post Assets::AuditTrail
    after_put Assets::AuditTrail
    after_delete Assets::AuditTrail

    def initialize(url, username = nil, password = nil)
      @connection = Faraday.new(url) do |faraday|
        faraday.basic_auth(username, password)
        faraday.request :url_encoded # form-encode POST params
        faraday.response :logger # log requests to STDOUT
        faraday.adapter :net_http # make resusts with Net::HTTP
        faraday.use Errors::RaiseError # include custom middleware
      end
    end

    def get(path, parameter = nil)
      @connection.get path, parameter
    end

    def post(path, data, headers = {})
      response = @connection.post path, data, headers
      run_callbacks :post
      return response
    end

    def put(path, data, headers = {})
      response = @connection.put path, data, headers
      run_callbacks :put
      return response
    end

    def delete(path)
      response = @connection.delete path
      run_callbacks :delete
      return response
    end
  end
end
```

2) An audit trail (AuditTrail) responsible for logging to the database.

```
module Assets
  class AuditTrail
    def self.after_post(obj)
      puts 'IN THE AFTER POST!!!'
    end

    def self.after_put(obj)
      puts 'IN THE AFTER PUT!!!!'
    end

    def self.after_delete(obj)
      puts 'IN THE AFTER DELETE!!!!'
    end
  end
end
```

Each time a PUT, POST or DELETE request is made I want to log the transaction in the database, via my AuditTrail class. I set this up using ActiveModel::Callbacks.

I am curious how I can access my function parameters in the AuditTrail functions? For example, when I enter the AuditTrail.after_post function is there a way to access the path, data, headers and response from the post function?

Answer (score 0):

The `obj` param in your callback methods is a reference to the ApiClient instance that the callback is called from.  I think if you store the call response to an instance variable, you should be able to parse the data you want in the callback method.